# Centering a Child Div over a Grid Layout

Tags: html, css

I have created a basic grid, which covers the entirety of the page using 1fr for the columns, and 1fr for the number of rows. This grid is created using a parent div.

The child div is what I want to center in the middle of the assigned grid. I have assigned the child position absolute, and the parent position relative- and used the following code which several sources have referred to for centering, and which does work to center the element when I delete the grid, and specify a height and width for the parent element.

But why can't I center a div over a parent that is in a grid? Vertically, it does not move, and worse, when I inspect the page the grid itself seems to have moved. Any idea what is going on with my grid and how to center elements over it?

```css
.parent-wrapper{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(8,minmax(min-content,1fr));  
  grid-template-rows:repeat(3,1fr);
  position:relative;
  background: red;  /* ADDED TO SEE BETTER */
  height: 200px;    /* ADDED TO SEE BETTER */
}

.child-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-wrapper">
  <div class="child-wrapper">
    <h1>CENTER ME</h1>
    <p>centered paragraph</p>
  </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Your `.parent-wrapper`do not have any height, is there a reason for that ?

Comment: The height was supposed to be repeat(3, 1fr)- the height of the screen broken down into three fractional units.

Answer (score 0):

Try use height

```css
.parent-wrapper{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(8,minmax(min-content,1fr));  
  grid-template-rows:repeat(3,100px);
  position:relative;
}

.child-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-wrapper">
  <div class="child-wrapper">
      <h1>CENTER ME</h1>
      <p>centered paragraph</p>
  </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: That works! I am not sure why using fractional units on the width is ok, but it was messing up with fractional units on the height. When I switched to pixels, as you suggested it did work.